# Как изменить цвет рамки поиска?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, вёрстка

При нажатии на поле ввода запроса поиска появляется рамка оранжевого цвета. Подскажите, как изменить цвет рамки?

Comment: `border` или `outline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-свойство "border-color" поля ввода